# Работа с текстовыми файлами и преобразования над полученными данными

Tags: java

**Входные данные :**

```
Иванов газета 10
Петров ручка 5
Николаев тетрадь 3
Иванов ручка 2
Николаев ручка 1
Петров тетрадь 2
Николаев газета 1
```

**Выходные данные :**

```
Иванов : газета - 10 шт ; ручка - 5 шт ;
Николаев : газета - 1 шт ; ручка - 1 шт ; тетрадь - 3 шт;
Петров : ручка - 5 шт ; тетрадь - 2 шт;
```

**Код :**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 *
 * @author Марат
 */
public class Semnadcat2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://SomeDir//notes3.txt"));
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            customers.add(new Customer(currentLine));
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        String [] a = new String[customers.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            Customer customer = customers.get(i);
            System.out.println(customer.getSurname() + " | " + customer.getProduct() + " | " + customer.getAmount());
            a[i] = customer.getSurname();
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
            String k = a[i];
            for (int j = 1; j < customers.size(); j++) {
                if (k.equals(a[j])) {
                    a[j] = "";
                }
            }
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Customer {
    private String mSurname;
    private String mProduct;
    private int mAmount;

    public Customer(String line) {
        String[] customer = line.split(" ");
        mSurname = customer[0];
        mProduct = customer[1];
        mAmount = Integer.parseInt(customer[2]);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return mSurname;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return mProduct;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return mAmount;
    }

}
```

**Ошибки :**

Не получается получить необходимый вид выходных данных на консоль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- для вывода по именам нужно группировать наборы `Customer` по этому самому имени. Сделать это можно с помощью `HashMap`, ключом в котором будет выступать имя, а значение - список `Customer`.
- Для суммирования количества одного типа товаров нужно проверять, есть ли уже такой товар в списке.

В классе `Customer` нужно добавить метод `addAmount`:

```
public void addAmount(int amount)
{
    mAmount += amount;
}
```

Основной класс:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SortedMap<String, ArrayList<Customer>> nameToCustomers = new TreeMap<>();
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")))
    {
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Customer newCustomer = new Customer(currentLine);
            String name = newCustomer.mSurname;
            if (!nameToCustomers.containsKey(name))
            {
                nameToCustomers.put(name, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            ArrayList<Customer> customers = nameToCustomers.get(name);
            boolean found = false;
            for (Customer customer : customers)
            {
                if (customer.mProduct.equals(newCustomer.mProduct))
                {
                    customer.addAmount(newCustomer.getAmount());
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                customers.add(newCustomer);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { }
    for (String name : nameToCustomers.keySet())
    {
        System.out.print(name + ": ");
        for (Customer customer : nameToCustomers.get(name))
        {
            System.out.print(customer.getProduct() + " - " + customer.getAmount() + "; ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: при к примеру вот таком вводе данных :Ivanov paper 10
Petrov pens 5
Ivanov marker 3
Ivanov paper 7
Petrov envelope 20
Ivanov envelope 5

Comment: он выведет,что 
Ivanov: paper - 10; marker - 3; paper - 7; envelope - 5;

Comment: а как суммировать paper в данном случае?Т.е. он выписывает как отдельные фрагменты,а не как целые

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров об этом стоило сразу упоминать в вопросе. Доработаю код.

Comment: прошу прощенья)просто возникла такая мысль)

Comment: ожидаю лицезреть Ваш замечательный код)

Comment: а как отсортировать вывод по фамилиям?Т.е.чтобы фамилии сортировались по алфавиту

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров вот про сортировку по именам забыл уже я. Добавил всё в код.

Comment: @Regent это юноша любит менять условия и не принимать ответы.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman "любит не принимать ответы" - это вы исходите из того, что только 2 из 10 его вопросов не имеют принятого ответа? Насчет условий за все вопросы говорить не буду, но у меня пока что проблем с ответами на эти вопросы не было.

Comment: @Regent у вас код работает? в NetBeans артефакты кругом в виде cannot find symbol и т.д.

Comment: @Regent у меня в коде нет метода addAmount

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров да, про этот метод я второпях забыл упомянуть. Сейчас добавил его в ответ. Код работает.

Comment: @Regent не могли бы прикрепить код вашего класса Customer?

Comment: @Regent всё нашел)

Comment: @Regent если использовать SortedMap, то можно обойтись без сортировки и уменьшить количество контейнеров до 1.

Comment: @Regent если я когда-нибудь изобрету нечто на Java - я упомяну о Вас! Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, стоило `SortedMap` взять.

Comment: @Regent посмотрите мой вариант ниже. С SortedMap все значительно короче.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListOfItems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // вместо файла использовал строку - суть не меняется
        String input = "Иванов газета 10\n" +
                "Петров ручка 5\n" +
                "Николаев тетрадь 3\n" +
                "Николаев тетрадь 3\n" +
                "Иванов ручка 2\n" +
                "Иванов ручка 2\n" +
                "Николаев ручка 1\n" +
                "Петров тетрадь 2\n" +
                "Николаев газета 1\n";

        SortedMap<String, Customer> people = new TreeMap<>();
        StringTokenizer lines = new StringTokenizer(input, "\n");
        while (lines.hasMoreElements()) {
            String line = lines.nextToken();
            String[] columns = line.split(" ");
            // нашли или создали клиента
            Customer customer = people.computeIfAbsent(columns[0], Customer::new);
            // добавили клиенту элемент в список
            customer.addItem(columns[1], Integer.parseInt(columns[2]));
        }
        people.forEach((s, customer) -> System.out.println(customer));
    }

    static class Customer {
        private String name;
        private Map<String, Item> items;

        public Customer(String name) { this.name = name; items = new HashMap<>(); }

        public void addItem(String name, int quantity) {
            Item item = items.computeIfAbsent(name, Item::new);
            item.changeQuantity(quantity);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + items.values().stream().map(Item::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ; "));
        }
    }

    static class Item {
        private String name;
        private int quantity;

        public Item(String name) {
            this(name, 0);
        }

        public Item(String name, int quantity) { this.name = name; this.quantity = quantity; }

        public void changeQuantity(int delta) {
            quantity += delta;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return name + " - "  + quantity + "шт"; }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Item)) return false;

            Item item = (Item) o;

            return name.equals(item.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return name.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Regent теперь есть суммирование.